# Spivak, Ch 12 Appendix, Prob. 5: Parametric curve $(u(t),v(t))$. Show line from furthest point Q on curve to point P is perpendicular to tangent at Q.

Tags: calculus, parametric

The following problem appears in Spivak's Calculus, appendix to chapter 12, "Parametric Representation of Curves"

> 5. Let $x=u(t)$, $y=v(t)$ be the parametric representation of a curve, with $u$ and $v$ differentiable, and let $P=(x_0,y_0)$ be a point on
>    the plane. Prove that if the point $Q=(u(\bar{t}), v(\bar{t}))$ on the
>    curve is closest to $(x_0,y_0)$, and $u'(\bar{t})$ and $v'(\bar{t})$
>    are not both $0$, then the line from P to Q is perpendicular to the
>    tangent line of the curve at Q (see figure below). **The same result
>    holds if Q is furthest from $(x_0,y_0)$**.

[image]

My question is about the final comment:

> The same result holds if Q is furthest from $(x_0,y_0)$.

**How do we show this?**

Here is a solution to the problem of showing the result for Q being closes to $(x_0,y_0)$

The square of the distance between P and $(u(t), v(t))$ is

$D^2(t)=(u(\bar{t})-x_0)^2+(v(\bar{t})-y_0)^2$

Note that $D^2$ is

- defined for all $t$
- bounded below by $0$
- differentiable (since $u$ and $v$ are)
- has a minimum on any closed interval (because it is continuous)

By assumption, $(u(\bar{t}),v(\bar{t}))$ is the point  on the curve closest to $(x_0,y_0)$, and therefore it is the minimum of $D^2$.

Were this assumption absent, we wouldn't be able to conclude that $D^2$ has a minimum in any open interval, correct?

The derivative $(D^2)'(\bar{t})$ must be zero since the minimum there occurs in the interior of any interval containing it.

$$(D^2)'(\bar{t})=2(u(\bar{t})-x_0)u'(\bar{t})+2(v(\bar{t})-y_0)v'(\bar{t})=0\tag{1}$$

One way to view $(1)$ is as a dot product

$$(u'(\bar{t}), v'(\bar{t})) \cdot (u(\bar{t})-x_0, v(\bar{t})-y_0)=0\tag{2}$$

$(u'(\bar{t}), v'(\bar{t}))$ is a vector tangent to the curve at at Q. $(u(\bar{t})-x_0, v(\bar{t})-y_0)$ is the vector from P to Q. If $\theta$ is the angle between these vectors, then $(2)$ tells us that $\cos{\theta}=0 \implies \theta=\frac{\pi}{2}$.

**The solution manual reaches this conclusion using a slightly different approach.**

Consider two possible cases

Case 1: $u'(\bar{t}) \neq 0$

From $(1)$, we can divide by $u'(\bar{t})$, to obtain

$$\frac{v'(\bar{t})}{u'(\bar{t})}\cdot \frac{y_0-v(\bar{t})}{x_0-u(\bar{t})}=-1$$

$\frac{v'(\bar{t})}{u'(\bar{t})}$ is the slope of the tangent line at $(x,f(x))=(u(\bar{t}), v(\bar{t}))$, and $\frac{y_0-v(\bar{t})}{x_0-u(\bar{t})}$ is the slope of the line that from Q to P.

Case 2: $u'(\bar{t})=0$

By assumption $u'(\bar{t})$ and $v'(\bar{t})$ are not both zero at the same time, so $v'(\bar{t})\neq 0$. Therefore, the tangent vector $(u'(\bar{t}), v'(\bar{t}))$ at $(u(\bar{t}), v(\bar{t}))$ is parallel to the y-axis.

But then from $(1)$ we have

$$(v(\bar{t})-y_0)v'(\bar{t})=0$$

$$\implies (v(\bar{t})-y_0)=0$$

$$\implies (v(\bar{t})=y_0)=0$$

That is, P and Q have the same y-coordinate. The line between them is thus parallel to the x-axis, and perpendicular to the tangent line which is parallel to the y-axis.

**Now let me go back to my original question.** It seems that what we can say is that if there is a point on the curve the is the most distant from P, then it will have $(D^2)'(t_{max})=0$. Therefore, all the calculations we just went through will be true for that point. Is this why Spivak makes the comment in bold?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> It seems that what we can say is that if there is a point on the curve the is the most distant from P, then it will have $(D^2)'(t_{max})=0$. Therefore, all the calculations we just went through will be true for that point. Is this why Spivak makes the comment in bold?

I think you've answered your own question, but here's another way to look at it. Say that the max distance is a constant, $M$. Define a new function, say $E^2=M^2-D^2$. then $E^2$ is bounded below by $0$ and so forth, and everything else in either of the two solutions just applies as-is, since the derivative of $M^2$ is zero.

(This is why the sun is directly overhead on the winter solstice at the equator at noon. https://www.weather.gov/cle/seasons)

Comment: I am trying to think about edge cases that are reasonable but (I assume) violate one of the premises of the problem. Let me try to describe a scenario. Let P be the point $(a,0)$, $a>1$, on the x-axis. Now consider the parametric equation $(x,\sqrt{1-x^2}+1)$, for $x \in [-1,1]$. This represents the top half of a circle of radius 1 centered at $(0,1)$. The closest and farthest points to P are the endpoints of the parametrized curve, where there is not tangent I believe. Since in this example the perpendicularity condition that I proved isn't true, which assumption of the problem is violated?

Comment: @evianpring the assumption that it's in the interior of any interval.

Comment: That assumption doesn't seem to be explicitly stated by Spivak though right?

Comment: @evianpring I don't have a copy of that book but I assume that is part of the definition of tangent line since it doesn't seem to be well-defined at the ends of the lines. Anyway your objection applies in exactly the same way if the nearest point is at the end of a line, so I didn't realise that was the nature of your question.

Comment: It's actually an extra question. You are right: I answered my own question with the observations I made in my original post.